# Regra do For em C

Tags: c, for

Tenho uma duvida quanto ao ciclo for , ou seja, tenho uma instrução for e tenho de obter o resultado que a maquina dava. 
tenho isto :

```
for(x=2,Y=1;X < 11;x++)y+=x++
```

Sei que a variavel X começa em 2 e Y em 1.
Sei que enquanto X for menor que 11 faz um ciclo. 
Aqui está o meu problema. Qual ciclo. faço x+1 até X ter o valor de 11? Ou faço a regra de fora que é:

```
  x=x+1
  y=y+x
```

Obrigado

Comment: Queria dizer instrução . 
Tão complicado pois não consigo decifrar este código. O que quero é saber o resultado final de X e Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para entender melhor, segue seu código com algumas instruções para *debug*:

```
int x;
int y;

for( x=2, y=1; x<11; x++ ) {
    printf("antes  x = %d, y= %d \n", x, y );
    y += x++;
    printf("depois x = %d, y= %d \n", x, y );
}
printf("final  x = %d, y= %d \n", x, y );
```

Eis o resultado:

```
antes  x = 2, y= 1 
depois x = 3, y= 3 
antes  x = 4, y= 3 
depois x = 5, y= 7 
antes  x = 6, y= 7 
depois x = 7, y= 13 
antes  x = 8, y= 13 
depois x = 9, y= 21 
antes  x = 10, y= 21 
depois x = 11, y= 31 
final  x = 12, y= 31
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/VXcNa0)**.

Resumidamente, a ordem de execução é essa:

```
for( x=2,y=1; X < 11; x++ ) y += x++
     ---1---  ---2--  -5-   --3- -4-
```

depois do 5º passo, retorna ao 1º, até a condição do 2º dar *false*.

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Já sei o que me estava a falhar. Estava a fazer primeiro a instrução nº 4 e depois a 3. Obrigado

Comment: @ChrisAdler para fazer como você disse, a linha teria que ser assim: `for( x=2,y=1; X < 11; x++ ) y += ++x` . Quando o `++` vem antes da variável, ela é processada antes da expressão de fora (é o pré incremento). Quando o `++` vem depois, ele só é calculado depois da expressão (pós incremento). Mesma coisa para o `--`

Answer (score 1):

Todo o `for` pode ser substituido por um `while`.

Talvez aches a sintaxe do `while` mais intuitiva :-)

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) body;
for (initialization; condition; increment) {body};

initialization;
while (condition) {
    body;
    increment;
}
```

No teu caso especifico, o codigo fica

```
// for (x = 2, y = 1; x < 11; x++) y += x++;
x = 2; y = 1;
while (x < 11) {
    y += x++;
    x++;
}
```

Onde se ve muito bem que `x` vai ser incrementado 2 vezes em cada vez dentro do ciclo.