# Calcular sequência de números triangulares menores que 1000

Tags: c++

Sou iniciante em programação e estou com dificuldade no seguinte problema:

> **Faça um programa que calcule e imprima todos os números triangulares menores do que 1000.**
>
> Um [número triangular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_triangular) é um número natural que pode ser representado na
>   forma de triângulo equilátero. Para encontrar o n-ésimo número
>   triangular a partir do anterior basta somar-lhe n unidades. A
>   sequência dos números triangulares (sequência A000217 na OEIS),
>   começando pelo 0-ésimo termo, é:
>
> 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Meu código ficou assim:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int b, a;
    for (a = 0, b = 0; b < 1000;a++){
        b = (a + 1) + b;
        cout << b << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O único problema é que quando eu compilo, ele vai até o 1035.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que o `for` testa a condição antes de executar o bloco interno, então o teste `b < 1000` ocorre antes do `b = (a + 1) + b;`.

Uma solução simples seria passar o cálculo para dentro do for:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int b, a;
    for (a = 0, b = 0; b < 1000; b = (a + 1) + b, a++) {
                              // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              // isto é processado ao final do bloco
                              // atenção à ordem do b antes do a++
        cout << b << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/XD53f4)**.

O código acima equivale a inverter a posição da "impressão":

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int b, a;
    for (a = 0, b = 0; b < 1000;a++){
        cout << b << endl;
        b = (a + 1) + b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/iFd7ca)**.

Mais em:

> [Regra do For em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114452/70)

> [Não consigo aprender sintaxe for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33674/70)

Answer (score 3):

O problema está que você primeiro incrementa o valor de `b`, para depois exibí-lo. Se você apenas inverter a ordem funcionará:

```
int main(){
    int b, a;
    for (a = 0, b = 0; b < 1000;a++){
        cout << b << endl;   //  <---+-- Essas duas linhas foram invertidas
        b = (a + 1) + b;     //  <---+
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Você pode, inclusive, simplificar isso incrementando o número junto na estrutura do `for`:

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 1, numero = 0; numero < 1000; i++, numero += i+1) {
        cout << numero << endl;
    }
}
```

O nome das variáveis não influencia, mas assim achei mais legível o código do que `a` e `b`.